# Rails business rule using validates_with getting uninitialized constant Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write my first business rule using validates_with.  I don't want events (labor) entered if a work order has a status of "WAPPR" (waiting on approval).

This is in my events model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :workorder_id
  validates_with ::WOStatusValidator
  ...
end

class WOStatusValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.workorder.wostatus.statuscode == "WAPPR"
      record.errors[:base] << "Can't enter labor if workorder status is WAPPR"
    end
  end
end
```

But, I get this:

```
undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

Thanks for the help!!

UPDATE

The rack session has this:

{"session_id"=>"52c6e4be5eeba78e5954a2997d9cac73", "_csrf_token"=>"kf1CYslb/rVmTWjoD4Qn4l1vZCeCwQOgg3VEYLqNTTg=", "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [11], "$2a$10$EHEjfT/B1jsjNIoR5.oJ2."], "flash"=>#, @closed=false, @flashes={:workorder_id=>2, :employee_id=>5, :comment=>true}, @now=nil>}

And workorder/2 has wostatus/235 and that wostatus has statuscode = WAPPR

The action_name is "new"

The error comes from this code in visible_action?(gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb

Line 36

```
35       def visible_action?(action_name)
36         return @visible_actions[action_name] if @visible_actions.key?(action_name)
37         @visible_actions[action_name] = !hidden_actions.include?(action_name)
38       end
```

UPDATE2

jvnill suggested:

```
record.errors.add :base, "Can't enter labor if workorder status is WAPPR"
```

- I made that change and now I get

  "uninitialized constant WOStatusValidator"

It's from line 11 of this code:

```
8 class RoutingError < ActionControllerError #:nodoc: 
9 attr_reader :failures 
10 def initialize(message, failures=[]) 
11 super(message) 
12 @failures = failures 13 end 14 end
```

UDPATE3

Am I even using the right type of coding for enforcing this business rule?  Is there a better way?

Comment: where does the error stems from? give details about the exception

Comment: your edit doesn't help

Comment: I'm trying to add a new event to a work order that has a wostatus = WAPPR

Comment: so `@visible_actions` is nil, simply

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
validates_with WOStatusValidator
```

With:

```
validates_with ::WOStatusValidator
```

It explicitly tell Rails to look for a top level constant.

Comment: Thanks !  But, now I get undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: can you try `record.errors.add :base, "Can't enter labor if workorder status is WAPPR"`?

Comment: jvnill - I used your change and now I get "uninitialized constant WOStatusValidator"  It's from line 11 of this code:     `8   class RoutingError < ActionControllerError #:nodoc:
    9     attr_reader :failures
   10     def initialize(message, failures=[])
   11       super(message)
   12       @failures = failures
   13     end
   14   end`